# Interpolating intermediate points in R based on conditions

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
test <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1325394000, 1325394360, 
                                  1325394720, 1325395080, 1325395440, 1325395800, 1325396160, 1325396520, 
                                  1325396880, 1325397240, 1325397600, 1325397960, 1325398320, 1325398680, 
                                  1325399040, 1325399400, 1325399760, 1325400120, 1325400480, 1325400840, 
                                  1325401200, 1325401560, 1325401920, 1325402280, 1325402640, 1325403000, 
                                  1325403360, 1325403720, 1325404080, 1325404440, 1325404800, 1325405160, 
                                  1325405520, 1325405880, 1325406240, 1325406600, 1325406960, 1325407320, 
                                  1325407680, 1325408040, 1325408400, 1325408760, 1325409120, 1325409480, 
                                  1325409840, 1325410200, 1325410560, 1325410920, 1325411280, 1325411640, 
                                  1325412000, 1325412360, 1325412720, 1325413080, 1325413440, 1325413800, 
                                  1325414160, 1325414520, 1325414880, 1325415240, 1325415600, 1325415960, 
                                  1325416320, 1325416680, 1325417040, 1325417400, 1325417760, 1325418120, 
                                  1325418480, 1325418840, 1325419200, 1325419560, 1325419920, 1325420280, 
                                  1325420640, 1325421000, 1325421360, 1325421720, 1325422080, 1325422440, 
                                  1325422800, 1325423160, 1325423520, 1325423880, 1325424240, 1325424600, 
                                  1325424960, 1325425320, 1325425680, 1325426040, 1325426400, 1325426760, 
                                  1325427120, 1325427480, 1325427840, 1325428200, 1325428560, 1325428920, 
                                  1325429280, 1325429640, 1325430000, 1325430360, 1325430720, 1325431080, 
                                  1325431440, 1325431800, 1325432160, 1325432520, 1325432880, 1325433240, 
                                  1325433600, 1325433960, 1325434320, 1325434680, 1325435040, 1325435400, 
                                  1325435760, 1325436120, 1325436480, 1325436840, 1325437200, 1325437560, 
                                  1325437920, 1325438280, 1325438640, 1325439000, 1325439360, 1325439720, 
                                  1325440080, 1325440440, 1325440800, 1325441160, 1325441520, 1325441880, 
                                  1325442240, 1325442600, 1325442960, 1325443320, 1325443680, 1325444040, 
                                  1325444400, 1325444760, 1325445120, 1325445480, 1325445840, 1325446200, 
                                  1325446560, 1325446920, 1325447280, 1325447640, 1325448000, 1325448360, 
                                  1325448720, 1325449080, 1325449440, 1325449800, 1325450160, 1325450520, 
                                  1325450880, 1325451240, 1325451600, 1325451960, 1325452320, 1325452680, 
                                  1325453040, 1325453400, 1325453760, 1325454120, 1325454480, 1325454840, 
                                  1325455200, 1325455560, 1325455920, 1325456280, 1325456640, 1325457000, 
                                  1325457360, 1325457720, 1325458080, 1325458440, 1325458800, 1325459160, 
                                  1325459520, 1325459880, 1325460240, 1325460600, 1325460960, 1325461320, 
                                  1325461680, 1325462040, 1325462400, 1325462760, 1325463120, 1325463480, 
                                  1325463840, 1325464200, 1325464560, 1325464920, 1325465280, 1325465640, 
                                  1325466000, 1325466360, 1325466720, 1325467080, 1325467440, 1325467800, 
                                  1325468160, 1325468520, 1325468880, 1325469240, 1325469600, 1325469960, 
                                  1325470320, 1325470680, 1325471040, 1325471400, 1325471760, 1325472120, 
                                  1325472480, 1325472840, 1325473200, 1325473560, 1325473920, 1325474280, 
                                  1325474640, 1325475000, 1325475360, 1325475720, 1325476080, 1325476440, 
                                  1325476800, 1325477160, 1325477520, 1325477880, 1325478240, 1325478600, 
                                  1325478960, 1325479320, 1325479680, 1325480040, 1325480400, 1325480760, 
                                  1325481120, 1325481480, 1325481840, 1325482200, 1325482560, 1325482920, 
                                  1325483280, 1325483640, 1325484000, 1325484360, 1325484720, 1325485080, 
                                  1325485440, 1325485800, 1325486160, 1325486520, 1325486880, 1325487240, 
                                  1325487600, 1325487960, 1325488320, 1325488680, 1325489040, 1325489400, 
                                  1325489760, 1325490120, 1325490480, 1325490840, 1325491200, 1325491560, 
                                  1325491920, 1325492280, 1325492640, 1325493000, 1325493360, 1325493720, 
                                  1325494080, 1325494440, 1325494800, 1325495160, 1325495520, 1325495880, 
                                  1325496240, 1325496600, 1325496960, 1325497320, 1325497680, 1325498040, 
                                  1325498400, 1325498760, 1325499120, 1325499480, 1325499840, 1325500200, 
                                  1325500560, 1325500920, 1325501280, 1325501640), 
                                  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York"), 
                                predicted = c(3.448, 
                                   3.508, 3.566, 3.622, 3.675, 3.726, 3.775, 3.82, 3.863, 3.902, 
                                   3.938, 3.97, 3.999, 4.023, 4.044, 4.06, 4.072, 4.079, 4.081, 
                                   4.078, 4.07, 4.057, 4.038, 4.015, 3.985, 3.951, 3.91, 3.865, 
                                   3.815, 3.759, 3.699, 3.634, 3.565, 3.493, 3.417, 3.338, 3.256, 
                                   3.173, 3.089, 3.003, 2.917, 2.832, 2.747, 2.663, 2.581, 2.502, 
                                   2.424, 2.349, 2.277, 2.207, 2.141, 2.078, 2.017, 1.96, 1.905, 
                                   1.852, 1.802, 1.754, 1.707, 1.661, 1.616, 1.572, 1.528, 1.485, 
                                   1.442, 1.398, 1.355, 1.311, 1.268, 1.225, 1.182, 1.14, 1.099, 
                                   1.06, 1.023, 0.988, 0.957, 0.928, 0.904, 0.884, 0.868, 0.858, 
                                   0.853, 0.854, 0.86, 0.873, 0.892, 0.916, 0.947, 0.983, 1.024, 
                                   1.071, 1.123, 1.179, 1.239, 1.302, 1.369, 1.438, 1.51, 1.583, 
                                   1.658, 1.734, 1.81, 1.887, 1.963, 2.04, 2.115, 2.19, 2.265, 2.338, 
                                   2.41, 2.481, 2.551, 2.62, 2.688, 2.754, 2.819, 2.883, 2.945, 
                                   3.006, 3.066, 3.124, 3.18, 3.235, 3.288, 3.339, 3.388, 3.435, 
                                   3.48, 3.522, 3.561, 3.598, 3.632, 3.662, 3.689, 3.713, 3.733, 
                                   3.749, 3.761, 3.769, 3.772, 3.77, 3.764, 3.753, 3.737, 3.716, 
                                   3.69, 3.658, 3.621, 3.578, 3.531, 3.478, 3.42, 3.358, 3.29, 3.219, 
                                   3.143, 3.064, 2.982, 2.897, 2.809, 2.72, 2.63, 2.539, 2.448, 
                                   2.357, 2.267, 2.179, 2.093, 2.008, 1.927, 1.848, 1.773, 1.701, 
                                   1.632, 1.566, 1.504, 1.445, 1.389, 1.337, 1.286, 1.238, 1.192, 
                                   1.148, 1.106, 1.064, 1.024, 0.984, 0.945, 0.906, 0.868, 0.83, 
                                   0.793, 0.756, 0.721, 0.686, 0.654, 0.623, 0.595, 0.57, 0.548, 
                                   0.53, 0.516, 0.507, 0.503, 0.504, 0.512, 0.525, 0.545, 0.571, 
                                   0.603, 0.641, 0.686, 0.737, 0.793, 0.855, 0.921, 0.993, 1.068, 
                                   1.147, 1.23, 1.315, 1.402, 1.491, 1.581, 1.672, 1.763, 1.854, 
                                   1.945, 2.036, 2.125, 2.213, 2.3, 2.386, 2.47, 2.553, 2.634, 2.713, 
                                   2.79, 2.866, 2.94, 3.012, 3.082, 3.15, 3.217, 3.281, 3.344, 3.405, 
                                   3.463, 3.52, 3.574, 3.626, 3.676, 3.723, 3.767, 3.809, 3.847, 
                                   3.883, 3.916, 3.945, 3.971, 3.993, 4.012, 4.026, 4.037, 4.044, 
                                   4.046, 4.044, 4.037, 4.026, 4.01, 3.989, 3.963, 3.933, 3.897, 
                                   3.857, 3.813, 3.763, 3.71, 3.652, 3.591, 3.526, 3.458, 3.387, 
                                   3.314, 3.239, 3.163, 3.086, 3.008, 2.93, 2.853, 2.777, 2.702, 
                                   2.628, 2.556, 2.487, 2.42, 2.355, 2.293, 2.233), 
                              type = structure(c(NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                       .Label = c("", "high", "low"), class = "factor"), 
                                    datehell = c(NA, "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "8400", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "9900", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "8400", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "9900", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "8400", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                     "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), 
                                    .Names = c("datetime",  "predicted", "type", "datehell"), 
                                        row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
                                                    "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
                                                    "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
                                                    "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
                                                    "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
                                                    "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
                                                    "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
                                                    "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
                                                    "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", 
                                                    "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", 
                                                    "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", 
                                                    "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", 
                                                    "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", 
                                                    "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", 
                                                    "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", 
                                                    "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", 
                                                    "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", 
                                                    "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", 
                                                    "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", 
                                                    "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", 
                                                    "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", 
                                                    "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "210", 
                                                    "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", 
                                                    "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", 
                                                    "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", "237", 
                                                    "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", "245", "246", 
                                                    "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", "254", "255", 
                                                    "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", "263", "264", 
                                                    "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", "272", "273", 
                                                    "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", "281", "282", 
                                                    "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", "290", "291", 
                                                    "292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", "299", "300")
                                                  , class = "data.frame")
```

The head of the dataset looks like following:

```
> head(test)
             datetime predicted type datehell
1 2012-01-01 00:00:00     3.448 <NA>     <NA>
2 2012-01-01 00:06:00     3.508              
3 2012-01-01 00:12:00     3.566              
4 2012-01-01 00:18:00     3.622              
5 2012-01-01 00:24:00     3.675              
6 2012-01-01 00:30:00     3.726
```

The `type` column is checking the local `maxima`and `minima` of the `predict` column. When it is `minima`, then the `type` is 'low" and when it is "maxima" the type is "high".

I need to transform the `datetime` such that when type = "high", I need to add 140 minutes and when type = "low", I need to add 165 minutes.  In the date hell column, I have appropriate minutes in seconds so that I could add to the corresponding dates.

For the remaining `datetime` which have neither "high" nor "low" `type` I need to do the linear interpolation between high and low tide to find the appropriate time shift.

For example, row 19 is high tide with datehell = 8400 and row 83 is low tide with datehell = 9900. So, between row 19 and row 83 I need to do linear interpolation to fill the blank helltide column. I need to do repeat the same thing for rest of the data. All the columns between high and low or low and high needs to be filled with linear interpolation.

Please let me know if it is not clear.

From row 19 to row 83, after adding column datetime and datehell, expected output is

```
1/1/12 4:08 AM
1/1/12 4:14 AM
1/1/12 4:20 AM
1/1/12 4:27 AM
1/1/12 4:33 AM
1/1/12 4:39 AM
1/1/12 4:46 AM
1/1/12 4:52 AM
1/1/12 4:59 AM
1/1/12 5:05 AM
1/1/12 5:11 AM
1/1/12 5:18 AM
1/1/12 5:24 AM
1/1/12 5:31 AM
1/1/12 5:37 AM
1/1/12 5:43 AM
1/1/12 5:50 AM
1/1/12 5:56 AM
1/1/12 6:03 AM
1/1/12 6:09 AM
1/1/12 6:15 AM
1/1/12 6:22 AM
1/1/12 6:28 AM
1/1/12 6:34 AM
1/1/12 6:41 AM
1/1/12 6:47 AM
1/1/12 6:54 AM
1/1/12 7:00 AM
1/1/12 7:06 AM
1/1/12 7:13 AM
1/1/12 7:19 AM
1/1/12 7:26 AM
1/1/12 7:32 AM
1/1/12 7:38 AM
1/1/12 7:45 AM
1/1/12 7:51 AM
1/1/12 7:58 AM
1/1/12 8:04 AM
1/1/12 8:10 AM
1/1/12 8:17 AM
1/1/12 8:23 AM
1/1/12 8:30 AM
1/1/12 8:36 AM
1/1/12 8:42 AM
1/1/12 8:49 AM
1/1/12 8:55 AM
1/1/12 9:01 AM
1/1/12 9:08 AM
1/1/12 9:14 AM
1/1/12 9:21 AM
1/1/12 9:27 AM
1/1/12 9:33 AM
1/1/12 9:40 AM
1/1/12 9:46 AM
1/1/12 9:53 AM
1/1/12 9:59 AM
1/1/12 10:05 AM
1/1/12 10:12 AM
1/1/12 10:18 AM
1/1/12 10:25 AM
1/1/12 10:31 AM
1/1/12 10:37 AM
1/1/12 10:44 AM
1/1/12 10:50 AM
1/1/12 10:57 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a loop calculating the linear interpolation:

```
LH <- which( test$"type" %in% c("low","high"))

for ( n in 1:(length(LH)-1) )
{
  dh1 <- as.numeric(test$"datehell"[LH[n]])
  dh2 <- as.numeric(test$"datehell"[LH[n+1]])

  m <- LH[n]

  while ( m < LH[n+1] )
  {
    dt <- (dh1*(LH[n+1]-m) + dh2*(m-LH[n])) / (LH[n+1]-LH[n])
    test$"datetime"[m] <- test$"datetime"[m] + as.difftime(dt,units="secs")
    m <- m+1                           
  }
}

test$"datetime"[LH[length(LH)]] <- test$"datetime"[LH[length(LH)]] + as.difftime(dh2,units="secs")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#first set the first and last rows as appropriate
test[1,3]<-"low"
test[1,4]<-9900
test[300,3]<-"low"
test[300,4]<-9900


#find and save all the local extrema
highlows<-which(as.character(test$type) %in% c("high","low"))



#loop through the thresholds
for(Ind in highlows[1:(length(highlows)-1)]) {
  nextpos <- highlows[which(highlows==Ind)+1]

    #this sets the whole vector to the new values at once
    test[(Ind+1):(nextpos-1),4]<-as.numeric(test[Ind,4])+((as.numeric(test[nextpos,4])-as.numeric(test[Ind,4]))/(nextpos-Ind))*1:(nextpos-Ind-1)

}

test$datetime<-test$datetime+as.numeric(test$datehell)
```